# MYSQL Distinct results from a query

Tags: mysql

What i'm trying to do is get the DISTINCT results using a MYSQL query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT un.*, co.order_product_quantity AS product_num, cu.first_name, cu.surname, cp.product_name, cp.product_thumbnail AS prod_img, co.order_goods_cost, co.order_delivery_cost, co.order_status as status
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT order_unique_id AS o_id, order_date
            FROM cbs_orders
            GROUP BY order_unique_id
        ) un
            INNER JOIN cbs_orders co ON co.order_unique_id = un.o_id
            INNER JOIN cbs_users cu ON cu.id = co.order_user_id
            INNER JOIN cbs_products cp ON cp.product_id = co.order_product_id
        ORDER BY un.order_date DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page ";
```

I'm looking to get the DISTINCT order_unique_id from the query, i never wrote the query initially, i thought adding "SELECT DISTINCT order_unique_id" would solve the issue but it still brings back duplicate ids.

cheers for any help guys

Graham

Comment: DISTINCT selects distinct result rows, not field values.

Comment: the concept will return distinct rows, so you would need to do some additional manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to leverage `GROUP BY` correctly; `DISTINCT` won't help you in this situation. Additional, I'm pretty sure that sub-select is not needed.

Try this

```
 $sql = "SELECT un.order_unique_id AS o_id, un.order_date,
 co.order_product_quantity AS product_num, 
 cu.first_name, cu.surname, cp.product_name, 
 cp.product_thumbnail AS prod_img, co.order_goods_cost, 
 co.order_delivery_cost, co.order_status as status
   FROM cbs_orders AS un
   INNER JOIN cbs_orders co ON co.order_unique_id = un.o_id
   INNER JOIN cbs_users cu ON cu.id = co.order_user_id
   INNER JOIN cbs_products cp ON cp.product_id = co.order_product_id
     GROUP BY un.order_unique_id
     ORDER BY un.order_date DESC 
     LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page ";
```

This might produce odd results, because you are not applying [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to other columns. You may need to use those to get desired results.

Comment: Hi guys, if in the order table there is 3 x order_unique_id's 1 on each row, i wanted to initially just display it once, currently it loops out 3 times, i'm not the greatest with queries as yet lol i'm experimenting with the query, it seems overly complicated to me lol

Answer (score 0):

Let me hazard a guess that you want records for only the most recent order.  If this is the case, then you can do what you want, by properly aggregating the data:

```
SELECT un.*, co.order_product_quantity AS product_num, cu.first_name,
       cu.surname, cp.product_name, cp.product_thumbnail AS prod_img,   
       co.order_goods_cost, co.order_delivery_cost, co.order_status as status
FROM (SELECT order_unique_id AS o_id, max(order_date) as order_date
      FROM cbs_orders
      GROUP BY order_unique_id
     ) un INNER JOIN
     cbs_orders co
     ON co.order_unique_id = un.o_id INNER JOIN
     cbs_users cu
     ON cu.id = co.order_user_id INNER JOIN
     cbs_products cp
     ON cp.product_id = co.order_product_id
ORDER BY un.order_date DESC
LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page;
```

If you want only one row per order, then you need to figure out what to do with the products.  In my opinion, this interpretation is so different from your current question that you should ask another question, providing sample data and desired results.